# Rs232 - Why do I read what I just wrote?

Tags: raspbian, serial

I have connected my RPi to my laptop via an RS232 to TTL adapter and a RS232 to USB cable and tried to write to it in C.

On my laptop everything worked just fine.

But when I move to the production environment, I see from the Pc they have that the program that was made to communicate with the RPi reads what it just wrote.

In fact, if it tries to write a long string, it works, but when he tries to write a short string (the hex for "ack"), that very string "bounces" back and is read by the program.

Schematically:

- PC sends "message" to RPI
- RPI sends "ack_1" to PC
- PC sends "ack" to RPI
- Both PC and RPI read "ack" from the line

I can post part of the code that I use, if you think it's necessary.

For now I can tell you that I use standard functions from the RS232 C library.

My OS is Raspbian.

Comment: Do you think you might have wired it incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, I did. But the wiring is correct, I guess... I mean, everything works fine, I receive everything I need plus that single ack string that I just sent

Comment: Could you just clarify.  Are you plugging into the USB port on the Pi or the UART pins (8/10 on the Pi P1 header).

Comment: I am plugging the RS232 to ttl converter to the UART pins of the Rpi

Comment: I'd stop the Pi program and confirm that the serial link is OK by running something like minicom on the Pi.  Alternatively just cat </dev/ttyAMA0 from a terminal and it should show what the PC is transmitting.  Apologies in advance if you have already proven that the serial link is working correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Now, the program is stopped, and I can see what the PC is sending. I see it sends just what it should, no problem (in fact if it doesn't receive ACK, it doesn't send ACK in reply)... I tried to plug a 50 ft extension cable between the Pi and the Pc, and it works! No weird extra messages are coming from the pi! Could you help me understand this? Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16005/discussion-between-user3536411-and-joan).